# preg_replace not working for charachter \

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm trying to replace **\'** with **'** but it won't work

This is the text I want to replace from

> Using Twitter\'s @Anywhere Service in
>   6 Steps

and this is the code

```
$tutorial = "Using Twitter\'s @Anywhere Service in 6 Steps ";
echo $tutorial."<br /><br />";
$tut_title = preg_replace("/\\'/", "'", $tutorial);
echo $tut_title;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to bother with regular expressions for this. In this particular case, you can just use [stripslashes](http://php.net/stripslashes).

You can also use `str_replace("\\'", "'", $tutorial);`

For future regex reference, though, you would need to double-escape the backslash:

`$tut_title = preg_replace("/\\\\'/", "'", $tutorial);`

Why? because in your current form, you're passing the pattern `/\'/` to the regex engine, which is just trying to escape `'`

Comment: Yeah, use this approach, though for some reason, the output looked like it was working in my last answer.  Sorry about that.